# error restarting JBoss/Keycloak docker container

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am setting up a keycloak server using the [Jboss docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)(v.4.0.0.final) and I am encountering this error upon reboot:

```
.....
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
keycloak_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
keycloak_1  | 
keycloak_1  | 18:51:15,509 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@52734583 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.jboss.as.controller.notification.NotificationSupports$NonBlockingNotificationSupport$1@2211e00e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41133ff1[Shutting down, pool size = 50, active threads = 43, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 93]
keycloak_1  | docker_keycloak_1 exited with code 1
```

When I run the docker container for the first time, everything goes as planned. I can login, create roles, etc. I launch the container using [jhipster](http://jhipster.tech)'s keycloak script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:4.0.0.Final
    command: ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import", "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir", "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config", "-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING", "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000"]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_DATABASE=postgres
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

Am I shutting it down correctly?

Comment: At first, you can add the following environment lines, to get debug messages:

ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG

Maybe this will help you to find the problem.